# How to remove a .pdf's document restrictions?

Tags: pdf, restrictions

I need to remove some restrictions from a .pdf document:

[image]

I can't zoom or use any other buttons. The toolbar just isn't available. I never saw a .pdf file like this one.

Comment: Point us to a PDF link if you want a remotely useful answer.

Comment: If the PDF is protected, there's very little you can do to unprotect it.

Comment: You can try this if the PDF has permission pswd => gswin64c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sFONTPATH=%windir%/fonts;xfonts;. -sPDFPassword=123456 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dPassThroughJPEGImages=true -sOutputFile=OUTPUT.pdf INPUT.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- with `ghostscript`:

  ```
  gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%stdout% -c .setpdfwrite -f locked.pdf > unlocked.pdf
  ```
- with `pdf2ps` and `ps2pdf` (slower):

  ```
  pdf2ps locked.pdf - | ps2pdf - unlocked.pdf
  ```

  If the unlocked PDF contains error, try to decompose the commands (ps2pdf have sometimes problems with a streamed input):

  ```
  pdf2ps locked.pdf unlocked.ps
  ps2pdf unlocked.ps unlocked.pdf
  ```

Comment: Alternatively =>   gswin64c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sFONTPATH=%windir%/fonts;xfonts;. -sPDFPassword=123456 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dPassThroughJPEGImages=true -sOutputFile=OUTPUT.pdf INPUT.pdf