# Removing PDF usage restrictions

Tags: linux, pdf

I have several PDF documents which have the "no copy" and "no print" restriction bits set. Are there any free tools for removing such restrictions, on Linux?

I tried `pdf2ps | ps2pdf` but the size increase is horrible. The originals are fairly large too, so I'd rather use a local tool than a website.

Comment: Willing to write any code or are you wanting something out of the box?

Comment: Code is okay, although I have a feeling it'll be C, and my C skills are limited to "Hello world".

Comment: You could use iText; http://itextpdf.com/itext.php this can be done in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove security from a PDF file?](http://superuser.com/questions/179064/how-to-remove-security-from-a-pdf-file) and/or [How to remove a .pdf's document restrictions?](http://superuser.com/questions/210686/how-to-remove-a-pdfs-document-restrictions) also perhaps see: [Removing the password from a PDF file](http://superuser.com/questions/86266/removing-the-password-from-a-pdf-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FOSS-wise, there is [PDFCrack](http://pdfcrack.sourceforge.net/), not sure if it does actually remove the security though, it's just a password cracker. I generally turn to some free trial software, [A-PDF Restrictions Remover](http://a-pdf.com/security/restrictions_remover.htm), it's easier to use.

It might be a lot harder if it's a recent PDF version though, I think they really increased the security recently.

Comment: Ended up buying the A-PDF tool.

Comment: A-PDF tool wants to make changes to the computer. Why does a PDF editor need to change the machine's configuration? It is a classic violation of least privilege and is probably laced with malware.

Answer (score 104):

With [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ qpdf --decrypt restricted-input.pdf unrestricted-output.pdf
```

Comment: `qpdf` works very well. There is a convenient pre-built Windows binary, which is a plus.

Comment: This only works if you know the current password

Comment: @iamkhush This requires the password if the file is actually encrypted and requires a password for opening, but it removes the no-print/no-copy DRM just fine without.

Comment: worked like a charm to remove copy and print restrictions. thank you!

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

You can probably use [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). Something like

```
pdftk in.pdf output out.pdf allow AllFeatures
```

should do the job.

Comment: This would work if the password is known.

Comment: I'm probably a few years late, but the owner password does not have to be known for this, just the user password, if there's any. It warns you not to abuse the power to simply remove the owner password and the limitations altogether, but does it without further complaining. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: For whom it may concern, `pdftk` is written in java and requires JRE.

Comment: Thanks so much. I needed to OCR an Intel datasheet from the 80's, and `ocrmypdf` refused to run until I'd done this. `pdftk` works (at least the version in Debian).

Comment: I tried this, but it says 
```Error: Failed to open PDF file:
   in.pdf
   OWNER PASSWORD REQUIRED, but not given (or incorrect)
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.```

Answer (score 20):

If you've got `ghostscript` installed try simply:

```
gs -sPDFPassword=$PASS -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%stdout% -c .setpdfwrite -f locked.pdf > unlocked.pdf
```

Comment: +1 and [found a variation online](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/removing-password-from-pdf-on-linux/#comment-45548): `gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=unencrypted.pdf -c .setpdfwrite -f encrypted.pdf`. Worked for me in a few seconds, faster than brute-forcing a password...

Comment: Side note, in my case the original file was 10 MB, after [`gs`](http://www.ghostscript.com/) it was 3.7 MB.

Comment: @bufh It probably reduced the resolution. GhostScript defaults to something like 72 dpi unless you specify an alternative with something like `-r<dpi>` (eg. `-r300`). Also, make sure you pass `-dSAFER`. PostScript is a turing-complete programming language and, last I checked, GhostScript's default was to allow arbitrary filesystem access.